# Подскажите как изменить код чтобы преобразовать обьект из json в массив вот такого вида var a = { items: [{}, {}, {}] };

Tags: javascript, json

Здраствуйте. Помогите изменить код таким образом чтобы вывод обьектов из ДЖСОН файла заканчивался с уникальными записями в блоке 1 раз, потому что сейчас происходит проход в цикле 2 раза в зависимости от колличества обьектов - пример джсона //Файл json2.data содержание:

```
{"distance": {"unit": "m", "value": 0.5 },"convert_to": "ft"}
```

Пример кода index.html

```
 oAJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
 oAJAX.open("GET","data2.json",true);
 oAJAX.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var oData;
    var oOutput = document.getElementById("info");
    if ((oAJAX.readyState == 4) && (oAJAX.status == 200)) {
        var oData = JSON.parse(oAJAX.responseText);
        {
          //console.log(' Hello', oData.convert_to);
            var oP;
            var Dlinacount = oData.distance.lenght;
            for (i in oData.distance ){
              console.log(oData.distance[i]);
              console.log('Here', oData.distance.value);

              if (!oData.distance.value) {
                 break;
                }

              else{
                console.log(oData.distance)
                oP = document.createElement ("p");
            console.log(oData.distance[i])
            oP.textContent = oData.distance.unit + "   " + oData.distance.value; 
            oOutput.appendChild(oP);
              }
            
          }
      } 
    }

}
oAJAX.send();
```

Я так понимаю что необходимо проверять джсон обьект на наличие пустых ключей и значений. Но как это правильно записать используя код не совсем понятно.

Comment: Можете детальнее описать проблему? Какой ответ приходит(формат) и какой формат вы хотите получить на выходе? Из вашего вопроса очень сложно понять. У вас в примере объект с 4мя ключами, а вы ожидаете получить массив с объектом из 3-х ключей...

Comment: МНе нужно выводить только полностью на выход ИМПЕРСКУЮ СИ (ФУТЫ ЯРДЫ) переводя из метрической СИ (МЕТРЫ СМ ММ) в . Колличество обьектов и записией в массиве должно быть динамическим изменяемым, например таких значений может быть много. Вот в этом и сложность моя, я не знаю как правильно выводить данные если я хочу проверить на инициализацию обьекта oData.distance[i] в цикле и вижу что в нем 4 поля. Но вывод этого значения нужно сделать только 1 раз - я не знаю как настроить вывод из ДЖСОН ОБЪЕКТА с уникальными полями. четко ограниченное колличество раз - если все поля в обьектах заполнены.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос. Приведите пример входящего JSON, и какой выходной вариант вы хотите получить

Comment: Это вход
..................................
{"distance": {"unit": "m", "value": 0.5 },"convert_to": "ft"} 


Это выход - но я его как то в браузере хочу в табличке выводить просто, а может быть потом еще хочу через аякс форму прикрутить:
...................

{"unit": "ft", "value": 1.64}

Comment: Определитесь, чего вы хотите, а потом вопросы задавайте. `const result = {unit: oData.convert_to, value: convertFunction(oData.distance.value,  oData.distance.unit, oData.convert_to}`

Comment: Благодарю - да я пытаюсь сделать аналог ссайта вот такого в будущем https://www.metric-conversions.org/uk/dovzhini/futi-v-mietri.htm, однако на данный момент решил просто с json форматов данных потренироваться 

 просто вот и пытаюсь разобраться - благодарю за решение.